# Is there symbol conflict when loading two shared libraries with a same symbol

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, symbols

An application (**app**) depends on two shared librarys: **liba.so** and **libb.so**.
**liba** and **libb** have the same function of **void Hello()** but with different implementations. 
Load the two shared libraries at runtime and try to access the two versions of Hello().
I load liba.so and libb.so by poco C++ shared-library, but eventually it calls **dlopen()** to load shared libraries. Here's the code:

```
#include "Poco/SharedLibrary.h"
using Poco::SharedLibrary;
typedef void (*HelloFunc)(); // function pointer type


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string path("liba");
    path.append(SharedLibrary::suffix()); // adds ".so"
    SharedLibrary library(path);
    HelloFunc func = (HelloFunc) library.getSymbol("hello");
    func();

    std::string path2("libb");
    path2.append(SharedLibrary::suffix()); // adds ".so"
    SharedLibrary library2(path2);
    HelloFunc func2 = (HelloFunc) library2.getSymbol("hello");
    func2();

    library.unload();
    library2.unload();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, when app loads liba.so and libb.so by dlopen(), will there be any symbol conflict for the two Hello() implementations?
In fact, the code goes well, but I wonder whether there's **any potential risk** to load libraries like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, when app loads liba.so and libb.so by dlopen(), will there be any symbol conflict for the two Hello() implementations?

There is none. These are addresses returned, and both dynamically loaded libraries will live in a separate address space.

Even the dlsym function cannot be confused since you pass the handle returned by the dlopen function, so it would not by any mean become ambiguous.

(This would not even be an issue with overloading within the same library, respectively)

Comment: So is the behavior of dlopen different than load time dynamic linking that would link against the application's symbols instead of the library's if it finds one?

Answer (score 20):

TL;DR: Always use `RTLD_DEEPBIND` if you would like to prevent already loaded global symbols from hijacking your library when you dlopen() it.

When you load a library with dlopen you can access all symbols in it with dlsym and those symbols will be the correct symbols from that library and doesn't pollute the global symbol space (unless you used RTLD_GLOBAL). **But its dependencies are still resolved using the already loaded global symbols if available even if the library itself defines the symbol.**

Consider a third party library call it libexternal.so, external.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void externalFn()
{
    printf("External function from the EXTERNAL library.\n");
}
```

Then consider `liba.so` which unknowingly implements one privately (note the static keyword indicating internal linkage). liba.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void externalFn()
{
    printf("Private implementation of external function from A.\n");
}

void hello()
{
    printf("Hello from A!\n");
    printf("Calling external from A...\n");
    externalFn();
}
```

Then consider `libb.so` which unknowningly implements one and exports it, libb.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void externalFn()
{
    printf("External implementation from B\n");
}

void hello()
{
    printf("Hello from B!\n");
    printf("Calling external from B...\n");
    externalFn();
}
```

And the main application that links against libexternal.so then dynamically loads the two aforementioned libraries and call stuff in them, main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void externalFn();

int main()
{
    printf("Calling external function from main app.\n");
    externalFn();

    printf("Calling libA stuff...\n");
    void *lib = dlopen("liba.so", RTLD_NOW);
    void (*hello)();
    hello = dlsym(lib, "hello");
    hello();

    printf("Calling libB stuff...\n");
    void *libB = dlopen("libb.so", RTLD_NOW);
    void (*helloB)();
    helloB = dlsym(libB, "hello");
    helloB();

    printf("Calling externalFn via libB...\n");
    void (*externalB)() = dlsym(libB, "externalFn");
    externalB();

    return 0;
}
```

The build commands are:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Building External..."
gcc external.c -shared -fPIC -o libexternal.so

echo "Building LibA..."
gcc liba.c -shared -fPIC -o liba.so

echo "Building LibB..."
gcc libb.c -shared -fPIC -o libb.so

echo "Building App..."
gcc main.c libexternal.so -ldl -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN -o app
```

And when you run the `app` it prints:

```
Calling external function from main app.
External function from the EXTERNAL library.
Calling libA stuff...
Hello from A!
Calling external from A...
Private implementation of external function from A.
Calling libB stuff...
Hello from B!
Calling external from B...
External function from the EXTERNAL library.
Calling externalFn via libB...
External implementation from B
```

You can see that when libb.so calls `externalFn` the one from the `libexternal.so` will be called! But you can still access libb.so's externalFn() implementation by dlsym-ing it.

When can you run into this a problem? In our case when we ship libraries for Linux we try to make it as self contained as possible, so we link every third party library dependency statically if we can. But just adding libwhatever.a will cause your library to export all symbols in libwhatever.a
So if the consumer app also uses the system's preinstalled libwhatever.so then your library's symbol references to libwhatever's symbols will be linked against the already loaded library instead of the one you statically linked. And the result is crash or memory corruption if the two differs.

The workaround is using a linker script to prevent the exporting of the unwanted symbols to avoid confusing the dynamic linker.

But the problems unfortunately doesn't stop here.

LibA's vendor decides that it ships multiple libraries in a single plugin directory. So they move out their implementation of externalFn() into their own library, external2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void externalFn()
{
    printf("External function from the EXTERNAL2 library.\n");
}
```

Then the build script changes to build the new external library and move all the thing into the plugins directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Building External..."
gcc external.c -shared -fPIC -o libexternal.so

echo "Building External2..."
gcc external2.c -shared -fPIC -o libexternal2.so

echo "Building LibA..."
gcc liba.c libexternal2.so -shared -fPIC -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN,--disable-new-dtags -o liba.so

echo "Building LibB..."
gcc libb.c -shared -fPIC -o libb.so

echo "Installing plugin"
mkdir -p plugins
mv liba.so plugins/
mv libexternal2.so plugins/

echo "Building App..."
gcc main.c libexternal.so -ldl -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN,--disable-new-dtags -o app
```

It's clear that liba.c depends on libexternal2.so because we linked against it, we even set RPATH to make the linker look for it in the folder where it is and so even ldd shows it no reference to libexternal.so at all, only the libexternal2.so:

```
$ ldd liba.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff75870000)
    libexternal2.so => /home/calmarius/stuff/source/linking/plugins/./libexternal2.so (0x00007fd9b9bcd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd9b97d5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd9b9fdd000)
```

So change the app to load liba.so from the plugins directory.
So it should work correctly, right? Wrong! Run the app and you get this:

```
Calling external function from main app.
External function from the EXTERNAL library.
Calling libA stuff...
Hello from A!
Calling external from A...
External function from the EXTERNAL library.
Calling libB stuff...
Hello from B!
Calling external from B...
External function from the EXTERNAL library.
Calling externalFn via libB...
External implementation from B
```

**You can see, now even libA calls into the library the app linked against instead of the one the lib linked against!**

What's the solution? Since glibc 2.3.4 (which exists since 2004) there is an option `RTLD_DEEPBIND` if you want to avoid conflict with already global symbols you must always need to specify this flag when dlopen-ing libs. So if we change the flags to `RTLD_NOW | RTLD_DEEPBIND` we get what we expect when we run the app:

```
Calling external function from main app.
External function from the EXTERNAL library.
Calling libA stuff...
Hello from A!
Calling external from A...
External function from the EXTERNAL2 library.
Calling libB stuff...
Hello from B!
Calling external from B...
External implementation from B
Calling externalFn via libB...
External implementation from B
```

Comment: this is a much better explanation! this has greatly helped me debug a situation I've encountered!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Without knowing the caveats, it's very easy to create dynamic linking relateds bugs that takes a long time to debug.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve something like DEEPBIND via linker scripts? I.e. if I have library A that links to library B and dlopens library C later, is there a way to ensure that C doesn't see symbols from B? I.e. only export B symbols to A and no one else.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem just like this and I've made an example:

```
// lib.h
#pragma once

int libfunc();
```

Implementation uses a function called 'myfunc'

```
// lib.c
#include "lib.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int myfunc()
{
        return printf("lib myfunc()\n");
}

int libfunc()
{
        myfunc();
        return printf("libfunc()\n");
}
```

This is called from the main part of code where another 'myfunc' function is defined

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

int myfunc()
{
        return printf("main myfunc()\n");
}

int main(void)
{
        libfunc();
        return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
> gcc -shared -fPIC -o liblib.so lib.c
> file liblib.so
liblib.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=a66c7c56b191995df01dbb0a6a94e2358716b369, with debug_info, not stripped
> gcc main.c -o main -L. -llib
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
main myfunc()
libfunc()
>
```

As it can be seen it is not the function from the library that gets called but the one that is already resolved which is the one from main.c file.